# Convert Future[Seq[(String, String)]] to Future[Seq[(String)]]

Tags: scala, future, sequences

I am trying to convert Future[Seq[(String, String)]] to Future[Seq[(String)]] using the following:

```
sortedSeq.map(_._2)
```

so sortedSeq is of type Future[Seq[(String, String)]]

but I keep getting the error :

```
 value _2 is not a member of Seq[(String, String)]
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sortedSeq.map will apply the mapping to the Future, but you want it to apply to the elements of the Seq inside the future.

So something like:

```
sortedSeq.map(_.map(_._2))
```

so you map on the contents of the Seq in the future.

If you have a code sample that produces this to try it out it may be easier.

Comment: Also applies to the opposite nesting, e.g. List[Future[something]].